# document.documentelement.innerhtml with AngularJs behaving differently

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> document . DocumentElement . InnerHtml on Angularjs showing different behaviour any alternatives because it takes classes and bindings

Comment: `document . DocumentElement . InnerHtml` should that be `document . documentElement . innerHTML`? Also, you've said the same thing in the title and the body of the question ... can you please elaborate your issue with some actual detail!

Comment: Actually i need the entire copy of the html page that is in Angular Js but the document. documentElement . innerHtml also printing the binding and angular classes values ,,,is there any way to get the properties of Angular Js when we use document. documentElement. innerHtml